# Two SPA Angular2 apps based on one code

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am building an Angular2 application which will be Injected to my existing website. I need to inject this application on two different URL's:

1. My client site `www.mysite.com/user`
2. My admin panel `www.mysite.com/admin`

The problem I have is I am trying to build 2 SPA angular apps from the one code base, (so we can reuse components, etc)

I am planing to inject the application through javascript function `$('somecontainer').load(myAng2App.html)`. The idea is to use one application for the users and administrators because there will be many shared functionality(services). Administrator will have more options in his view.

The welcome page of the Angular2 app will be different for each user.
I was planning to create two home components:

1. Client

**component**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
    import {SharedComponent} from './shared/shared.component';   

    @Component({
           moduleId: module.id,
           selector: 'app-user',
           templateUrl: 'app.user.component.html',
           styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
           directives: [SharedComponent] 
    })

    export class AppUserComponent {
           title = 'User!';
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ParentCoachApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>index.html</h2>
  <app-user>Loading...</app-user>
    <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main.js');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Admin

**component**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
    import {SharedComponent} from './shared/shared.component';   

    @Component({
           moduleId: module.id,
           selector: 'app-admin',
           templateUrl: 'app.admin.component.html',
           styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
           directives: [SharedComponent] 
    })

    export class AppAdminComponent {
           title = 'Admin!';
    }
```

**admin.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ParentCoachApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>index.html</h2>
  <app-admin>Loading...</app-admin>
    <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main.js');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with bootstrapping 2 components but if one of them is not available than there are errors:
`The selector "***" did not match any elements`

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppUserComponent , AppAdminComponent , environment } from './app/';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppUserComponent );
bootstrap(AppAdminComponent );
```

I am using **angular-cli**

Now I have 3/4 questions and I will be more than happy if someone can answer me and give some directions:

1. Is it possible to have 2 SPA apps from the one angular co debase, Is this the right way to solve this?
2. The problem which I have is how to tell `bootstrap(whichComponent)` to load on which site?

Comment: I would have thought that you could, but maybe with an extra layer of abstraction to what you have: I would try (if you're using SystemJS) to have a systemjs.config file for each project, in which you could map paths back to the common components. So you would have  a folder for each project, with each one pointing back to the common codebase where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem (it works in `angular-cli` up to version `1.0.0-beta.10` , because next versions are based on `Webpack` not on `Systemjs`).

Here is my solution:
main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppUserComponent , AppAdminComponent , environment } from './app/';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export class UserLoad(){
  constructor(){
      bootstrap(AppUserComponent);
  }
}
export class AdminLoad(){
  constructor(){
     bootstrap(AppAdminComponent);
  }
}
```

Then in **Client** `index.html`

```
<script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main').then(function(m){
           m.UserLoad();
        })
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

and in **Admin** `index.html`

```
<script>
     System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
         System.import('main').then(function(m){
            m.AdminLoad();
          })
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Like I mentioned this solution is not working in the newest version of `angular-cli` with `Webpack`. Tested on Angular rc.4 and Angular rc.5

If someone have an idea how can make it working I will be more than happy to see solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another module inside you typescript app folder with

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AdminModule} from "./admin.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AdminModule);
```

And then in admin layout:

```
<base href="http://localhost:20632/admin" />
<script>
    System.import('admin').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

That worked for me.